# How to set up one-to-zero-or-one relationship

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Given these EF 6 classes:

```
Public Class ClientSurvey

    Public Property ClientSurveyID As Integer

    Public Property SurveyTemplateID As Integer
    Public Overridable Property SurveyTemplate As SurveyTemplate

End Class

Public Class SurveyTemplate

    Public Property SurveyTemplateID As Integer

    Public Property ClientSurveyID As Integer?
    Public Overridable Property ClientSurvey As ClientSurvey

End Class
```

How do I set up the relationship between the two? If I just run the code "as is", I get this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine the principal end of an association 
between the types 'DBCTX.SurveyTemplate' and 'DBCTX.ClientSurvey'. The principal end of this
association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data 
annotations.
```

So based on my reading I added the following to the ModelBuilder:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity(Of SurveyTemplate)() _
            .HasOptional(Function(e) e.ClientSurvey) _
            .WithRequired(Function(e) e.SurveyTemplate)

        modelBuilder.Entity(Of ClientSurvey)() _
            .HasRequired(Function(e) e.SurveyTemplate) _
            .WithOptional(Function(e) e.ClientSurvey)
```

Not sure if I even needed both. Maybe one or the other would suffice? In any case, now I can run the app, but what I'm seeing is that if ClientSurveyID *is* set in the SurveyTemplate object, it uses the SurveyTemplateID as the foreign key into the ClientSurveys table instead of using the ClientSurveyID, which makes zero sense. So clearly I don't know what I'm doing. Can anybody explain how to set this up properly?

Answer (score 0):

Only one side is needed, and only one FK in that case is needed.

The relationship you describe is more of a many-to-one scenario than a 1-to-1. While one Client Survey can only be associated with a single template, can't that template serve multiple client surveys?

```
Public Class ClientSurvey

    Public Property ClientSurveyID As Integer

    Public Property SurveyTemplateID As Integer
    Public Overridable Property SurveyTemplate As SurveyTemplate

End Class

Public Class SurveyTemplate

    Public Property SurveyTemplateID As Integer

End Class



modelBuilder.Entity(Of ClientSurvey)() _
   .HasRequired(Function(e) e.SurveyTemplate) _
   .WithMany()
```

EF can enforce 1-to-1 in many-to-one scenarios, but keep in mind that it will only enforce this programmatically, there is nothing in the resulting schema itself that would prevent multiple client surveys representing the same template. This would use a `HasOptional` instead of the `WithMany()` and you can have a bi-directional navigation property if you like (I generally recommend avoiding bi-directional navigation properties unless it makes sense that both entities are treated as aggregate roots) In this case you would need to set up the Foreign Key expression explicitly to tell EF to use the SurveyTemplateId on the ClientSurvey to link the two. The default linking for 1-to-1 relationships is the Primary Key on both tables.

A classic example of 1-to-1 (or zero) would be things like table splitting info. For example if I have an Order table and a LaybyOrder which is extra details about an order when a Layby is done. There is only ever 0 or 1 LaybyOrder records for a given Order table so the LaybyOrder uses OrderId as it's PK (Like Order) and then there is a HasOptional(x => x.LaybyOrder).WithRequired()) From the Order config. Order is the aggregate so LaybyOrder doesn't need an Order reference. I can always get at the Layby info through the Order in Linq.

Comment: thank you for your response, although some of what you said was a little beyond my extremely-limited EF skills. :-D I was writing a comment to clarify the scenario here, but it was too long, so I added it as a separate answer (not sure if that's a StackOverflow-approved thing to do).

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to clarify something about Steve Py's answer. He made a totally reasonable assumption about the one-to-many relationship between the template and surveys, but it's not really true in this exact case. It is technically true that a single template can be assigned to multiple surveys, however, I'm not trying to model that in the EF model. The template does have an (optional) ClientSurveyID but that really represents where I want to consider the template as being "stored". I.e. if a template was designed for a specific survey I want to set the template's ClientSurveyID to that survey. This is really only used in the UI of our template editor to make it easier for the user to find the template later if they need to make changes to it. For templates that can be assigned to multiple surveys, the ClientSurveyID field should be left as null. In that case it would be considered a "global" template and goes in a different list in the template editor UI.

Having said that, I think it is confusing EF for me to try and use the ClientSurvey navigation property in this way. If I make a brand new "code first" EF project in Visual Studio it also thinks it needs to make a ClientSurveys collection navigation property and model it as a one-to-many relationship. So maybe I can't do what I'm trying to do.